# How can one diagonalize the second variation of action?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics

Suppose we have action $S[q]$ and its stationary path $q_s$, I want to find the orthonormal paths $\psi_n$ that can diagonalize the second variation of the action $S[q]$. How to do that? Thanks

Comment: With respect to which product are the paths orthonormal?

Comment: It's like asking how to diagonalize a matrix. In general you try to find its eigenvalues and eigenvectors.